# Write a SpareMatrix or IndexedTable to Feathers.jl

Tags: dataframe, julia

What is a decent approach to make either of these work?

```
using Feathers

sp_matrix = spzeros(Float64, 20, 3)

Feather.write("SparseMatrixCSC.test.feather", sp_matrix)


using IndexedTables

itable = NDSparse([fill("New York",3); fill("Boston",3)],
                          repmat(Date(2016,7,6):Date(2016,7,8), 2),
                          [91,89,91,95,83,76])

Feather.write("IndexedTables.test.feather", itable)
```

Answer (score 1):

DataFrames currently do not support creating columns from array views (though that makes sense and shouldn't be hard to implement). But DataFrames are not necessarily the best structure to work with sparse data; [IndexedTables](https://github.com/JuliaComputing/IndexedTables.jl) could be more appropriate. It's hard to tell without more details about your use case.

Comment: I'm trying to save the data to Feather.jl. Maybe it's easier to write a Source for it?

Comment: Yes, that would be more natural, and likely more efficient too.